# Can I tow a travel trailer or 5th wheel in the US with a foreign licence?

Tags: driving-licenses

I’m planning an RV trip around the central US (TX, NM, AZ, NV, CA, UT, CO, KS, OK). We were originally planning to rent a class A motorhome but are now considering renting a 3/4 or 1 ton truck and a large (~30’ long) travel trailer or 5th wheeler RV: cheaper, more space, and more flexibility to travel around after setting up camp.

I have a regular UK car driving licence and have driven in the US loads (cars, SUVs, trucks) and towed trailers in the UK. 
Am I legally allowed to tow in the US on my UK licence?
Are there any weight or other restrictions?

Comment: Any restrictions will be on a per state basis.

Comment: Your UK license will qualify you to drive in the US any vehicle that a regular from-the-US passenger car license will allow. The catch, however, is that each US state is free to set its own limits. The CA limits for a non-commercial license are shown here: https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/cdl_htm/lic_chart. I'd *guess* that state requirements are similar to one another, and that other individual states' limits are discoverable online.

Comment: If you have a class BE licence, no one should question you.